# Help: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error) when trying to mount FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE NFS export on OpenIndiana Hipster GUI client

Tags: freebsd, nfs, bsd, illumos, openindiana

I have a FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE machine, hostname `DellOptiPlex390`. I would like to export the folders `/usr/home/jdrch/KeePass` & `/usr/home/jdrch/Sync` and mount them via NFS on an OpenIndiana Hipster GUI machine with IP address 192.168.0.71. My username, jdrch, is the same on both machines. I therefore have the following:

My `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
hostname="DellOptiPlex390"
zfs_enable="YES"
kld_list="sysctlinfo"
ifconfig_re0="DHCP"
linux_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
dsbdriverd_enable="YES"
sddm_enable="YES"
sshd_enable="YES"
nfs_client_enable="YES"
webmin_enable="YES"
smartd_enable="YES"
ntpd_enable=YES
ntpd_sync_on_start=YES
rpcbind_enable="YES"
nfs_server_enable="YES"
nfsv4_server_enable="YES"
mountd_flags="-r"
mountd_enable="YES"
rpc_lockd_enable="YES"
rpc_statd_enable="YES"
```

My `/etc/exports`:

```
# Export /usr/home as read-write to OpenIndiana
/usr/home -alldirs -rw -mapall=MyFreeBSDUsername 192.168.0.71
```

I'm exporting `/usr/home` because it's a ZFS filesystem and the [exports(5) manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=exports&sektion=5&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) seems to imply that's necessary. FTA:

> All ZFS file systems in the subtree below the NFSv4 tree root must be exported

After any update to either of those files I restart both nfsd & mountd on the FreeBSD server.

Unfortunately, I haven't had any luck getting the export to mount.

Trying to mount one of the export's subfolders fails:

```
# mount DellOptiPlex390:/usr/home/jdrch/KeePass /export/home/jdrch/KeePass
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
nfs mount: mount: /export/home/jdrch/KeePass: Permission denied
```

Trying to mount the exported filesystem also fails:

```
# mount DellOptiPlex390:/usr/home/ /export/home/jdrch/KeePass
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
nfs mount: mount: /export/home/jdrch/KeePass: Permission denied
```

Using `sec=sys` in the mount command doesn't work, either:

```
# mount -F nfs -o vers=4,sec=sys DellOptiPlex390:/usr/home/jdrch/KeePass /export/home/jdrch/KeePass
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
NFS compound failed for server DellOptiPlex390: error 7 (RPC: Authentication error)
nfs mount: mount: /export/home/jdrch/KeePass: Permission denied
```

Substituting the FreeBSD server's IP address for its hostname has no effect.

What am I doing wrong?